# Vue does not return the correct value of the option. It returns the text

Tags: vue.js

I'm starting using Vue.js via CDN.

I have this select element:

```
<select @change="setValue($event.target.value)">
   <option>Choose</option>
   <option val="1">First</option>
   <option val="2">Second</option>
</select>
```

The problem is that Vue.js calls my `setValue` function with `Choose` when the user selects the `Choose` options. But when he selects the first or the second option, I get the correct value.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax for the HTML should be `value` and not `val`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

```html
<select>
    <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
</select>
```